# Networking - DNS services

Tags: networking, dns

It is a commonly used best practice to split an organization's DNS services, where some aspects of that service are hosted on the internal network or internetwork, and other aspects on at least one DMZ subnet.

Using topology diagrams as an illustration, explain this best practice and its advantage over a single host DNS service. (The best answer will divide DNS services onto 3 separate hosts.)

Answer (score 0):

This is worded like an assignment.  I'll skip the topology diagram and describe a typical split service (which can run on one server).  You should have at least two servers for your Internet DNS, however only one will be the master.  Programs like `bind` can provide split services, but some programs require two separate servers to be run.

Your external (Internet) server/service:

- should NOT provide caching DNS services for other domains;
- should provide zone transfers only to the DNS slaves for your domain;
- must provide data for the domains you want to be public; and
- should provide data only for the domains you want to be public.

Your internal (intranet) server/service:

- should provide a caching DNS service to your internal servers;
- must provide DNS forwarding to internal servers;
- may provide zone transfers to any internal server; and
- must provide DNS entries for all domains you want internally visible using internally accessible IP addresses.

For publicly published domains, it is common to have different IP addresses for external access and internal access.

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I get the internal/external separation what justification would there be though for involving a 3rd DNS host? redundancy?

Comment: @Nic I have no idea why a third host.   Possibly for separate internal and external slaves.